# Wrong Width For iAd-Bannerview

Tags: ios, iphone, adbannerview

I'm currently having problems with my ADBannerView. I tested the program on a 4.7-inch display, but the bannerview doesn't have the same width as the screen. I've already tried to change it programmatically and also in the storyboard, but that didn't make a difference. Here is a screenshot:

[image]